# Deleting data from a txt file in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I am creating my first GUI its a phonebook where users can add, show all, and delete contacts stored in a txt file. My problem here is I'm already able to write the datas to the txt file but I dont know to how delete a contact. Sorry guys newbee here.
This is how I put the data in a txt file and read it back.

```
private void ADD_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        inputs ++;
        String[] name;
        String[] number;
        String[] email;
        name   = new String[inputs];
        number = new String[inputs];
        email  = new String[inputs];
    //arrays the inputs

    for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
        name  [i] = name_field.getText();
        number[i] = number_field.getText();
        email [i] = email_field.getText();
    }
     name_field.setText("");
     number_field.setText("");
     email_field.setText("");

     try (PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("database.txt", true)))){

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            write.write("Name: "+name[i] + "\nNumber: " + number[i] + "\nEmail: " + email[i] +"\n\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
    }        

}                                    

private void SHOW_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    try {
        File f = new File("database.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String data = sc.nextLine();

            contact_area.append("\n " + data); 

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }        

}                                     

private void DELETE_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

// :( i dunno how to start

}
```

Comment: You have to rewrite the file, either by preloading the data into memory, manipulating it their and then writing it back when you need to, or, write each entry from the file to a new file, skipping the one you want to delete, then delete the old file and rename the new one in its place

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I thought of that too but my problem here is how to start coding the process. Its like the user entries the data he/she wanted to delete and the program would start rewriting the txt file and skips the data that matched the user's entry and replace the old txt file. I read about buffer reader and buffer writer but I'm having hard time in building the codes. :(

Comment: Since you're loading the entire file into memory anyway, you could simply write the `List` back to the file. Start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to write code to search through the text file and delete that line, the easiest way to do it would be to read the entire .txt file, and add each contact to an ArrayList so that the user can add, edit, and delete contacts as they choose.

Easiest way to do that would be to make a class called "Contact" which contains a name, number, and email in each instance.  Then you can manage each contact individually in the ArrayList. Here is what it would look like:

```
package contactbook;

public class Contact {

private String name, number, email;

public Contact(String name, String number, String email){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    this.email = email;
}

//put setters and getters here

}
```

Then, when you start your program create an ArrayList like so:

```
ArrayList<Contact> ListOfContacts = new ArrayList<>();

//Read the text file here and create a new contact for each one read
//Display all the existing contacts on the GUI
```

After that, your ActionListener for the button that adds a contact would look like this:

```
    ActionListener forAddButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            name = name_field.getText();
            number = number_field.getText();
            email = email_field.getText();

            Contact newContact = new Contact(name, number, email);

            ListOfContacts.add(newContact);
        }
    }
```

Display the contacts using a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and a delete button to delete the selected contact from the corresponding ArrayList element.  You would do this by calling `JTable.getSelectedRow()` on your table model to get the correct contact in your ArrayList:

```
    ActionListener forDeleteButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ListOfContacts.remove(myTable.getSelectedRow());
        }
    };
```

Then add a "save" button that overwrites the text file with the ArrayList `ListOfContacts`.  Hope this helps.